# Extension creating_DBLink_PostgreSQL_error

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have a problem with extension creating. I run following code:

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;`

And then I receive next error:

`ERROR:  permission denied to create "pg_catalog.dblink_pkey_results"`
`DETAIL:  System catalog modifications are currently disallowed.`

So, I haven't got thought about what I need to do in these case...

Comment: The `ERROR` message is pretty straightforward you cannot create objects in the system schema `pg_catalog`.  Just do `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink` or specify a non-system schema.